# Converting php code to Symfony class

Tags: php, symfony

i am using a simple php code with Activexpert to send sms here the intersting part

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
{
$_objSmsProtocolGsm = new Com("ActiveXperts.SmsProtocolGsm");
...
}
?>
```

it working fine but when i tried to insert it into my controller in symfony
i get an error

> Attempted to load class "Com" from namespace
>   "PFE\SiivtBundle\Controller" in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Symfony2.5\src\PFE\SiivtBundle\Controller\SiivtController.php
>   line 835. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

while my php code is simple and doesnt include or require any other files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message is self-explanatory. 
`Com` class doesn't exist in `PFE\SiivtBundle\Controller` namespace (which is current namespace in your controller class).

Try:

```
new \Com("ActiveXperts.SmsProtocolGsm");
```

The backslash before classname means that we're looking for a class in global namespace